# Query returning consecutive rows with matching value

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

Assume I have the following table:

```
data_point (creation_datetime DATETIME PRIMARY KEY, 
            data_point INTEGER);
```

I am looking for an SQL query that would not only tell me if the most recent entry has a data_point value of X, but how many consecutive rows after it also have X as a value.

For instance, assuming the following data:

```
creation_datetime       data_point
2012-10-31 12:00:00     0
2012-10-31 11:55:00     0
2012-10-31 11:50:00     0
2012-10-31 11:45:00     2
2012-10-31 11:40:00     0
```

If i had X=0, the number I would want back here would be 3, because the most recent value matches X, and the next 2 rows also match it.

I don't have any ID column or anything.  I could add one if need be, but I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) as num
from data_point
where creation_datetime > (
  select max(creation_datetime)
  from data_point
  where data_point <> 0
)
```

Counts the number of records after the last record that was not your desired value.

Comment: this is the simplest and most elegant solution.  thank you for your help.  it is much appreciated.

Comment: This solution works for the example but not in general.  For example, this will not work if the data points are (1,1,1,2,1) instead of (0,0,0,2,0).

Comment: @Lawrence - the way I read the requirements, X (0 in the example) is an input to the function. He wants to know if the most recent value is the given X, and also how many consecutive values are X.

Comment: @Chad, that makes sense, however, it would require an additional statement to determine X.  The way I understood the question, the OP was trying to do it all in one statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT max(creation_datetime), data_point, count(*)
FROM  data_points, (
  SELECT max(creation_datetime) time_of_last_data_point 
  FROM data_points 
  WHERE data_point <> (
    SELECT data_point FROM data_points ORDER BY creation_datetime DESC LIMIT 1
  )
) 
WHERE 
  creation_datetime > time_of_last_data_point
GROUP BY 
  data_point
```

Explanation:

- The nested select statement will find the entry `2012-10-31 11:45:00 | 2`.
- The outer select is limited to the records added after `2012-10-31 11:45:00`.

Note: you would have to clean this up a bit to use it with other databases.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @data_point table (creation_datetime DATETIME PRIMARY KEY, data_point INTEGER)
insert @data_point
      select '2012-10-31 12:00:00',     0
union select '2012-10-31 11:55:00',     0
union select '2012-10-31 11:50:00',     0
union select '2012-10-31 11:45:00',     2
union select '2012-10-31 11:40:00',     0

declare @x integer
set @x = 0

--solution 1
select COUNT(*) 
from @data_point 
where data_point = @x
and creation_datetime > 
(
    select max(creation_datetime)
    from @data_point 
    where data_point != @x 
)

--solution 2
select COUNT(*) 
from @data_point a
where data_point = @x
and not exists
(
    select top 1 1
    from @data_point b
    where data_point != @x 
    and a.creation_datetime < b.creation_datetime
)
```